# Selecting UTC date from Oracle and converting to UTC in Java

Tags: java, spring, oracle, timestamp, jdbctemplate

If I call in my app:

```
System.currentTimeMillis()
```

the result will be, let's say: 1536842771599, **which is**: GMT: Thursday, September 13, 2018 12:46:11.599 PM OR in **my local**: Thursday, September 13, 2018 3:46:11.599 PM GMT+03:00 DST

If I do the following select on the Oracle database installed locally:

```
select CAST(sys_extract_utc(SYSTIMESTAMP) AS DATE) from dual;
```

I get, through the following JdbcTemplate code:

```
jdbc.queryForObject(sqlCommand, new Object[0], Timestamp.class);
```

the following result:
[image]

Which in my opinion is already wrong because Timestamp usually represents localized time. Further, if I call:

```
myResult.getTime()
```

to get the long value, this will convert my time, which was around 12.46 PM, to the value 1536831971599, which is actually: GMT: Thursday, September 13, 2018 9:46:11.599 AM.

Obviously this is not good because it is 2 * GMT+03:00 (6 hours) behind my actual local time, and GMT+03:00 (3 hours) behind UTC time of the Database.

What I'm doing wrong? My only conclusion up until now is to avoid doing a **sys_extract_utc** on a database and let database return me local time which will be converted to UTC time when I will call getTime on the Timestamp instance.

Any explanation to this?

P.S.
Base on the answer that java.sql.Timestamp is UTC, I attach a screenshot of what debugger shows to me, and which is wrong, because it considers the result which is UTC to be GMT+03:00. So, it shows my time as 8.26 + 03:00. My local time is 11.26. If I call getTime on this instance of Timestamp, I will get a long value which if I put into https://www.epochconverter.com/ then I get Friday, September 14, 2018 8:26:06 AM GMT+03:00 DST or Friday, September 14, 2018 5:26:06 AM which is exactly 3 hours behind of what I actually have as UTC!

P.S.2
I use Spring JDBC 4.2.5-RELEASE. Can't use Instant with it, it throws exception that cannot convert Timestamp to Instant because it expects something that derives from Number. I cannot change this JDBC, even version, now, unfortunately.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

## tl;dr

You misunderstand the [`java.sql.Timestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) class.

- `java.sql.Timestamp` always represents a moment in UTC.
- [`java.time.Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) years ago replaced `Timestamp`.

Use only `Instant`, never `Timestamp`.

## `Instant`

The terrible `java.sql.Timestamp` class is now outmoded by the *java.time* classes, specifically `Instant`.

```
Instant.now()  // Capture the current moment in UTC.
```

## JDBC 4.2

As of JDBC 4.2, we can directly exchange *java.time* objects with the database. No need to ever again use the awful `Date`, `Calendar`, or java.sql classes.

Retrieve.

```
Instant instant = myResultSet.getObject( … , Instant.class ) ;
```

Insert.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , instant ) ;
```

> Timestamp usually represents localized time.

Incorrect. A `java.sql.Timestamp` represents a moment in UTC, always UTC, by definition. Likewise, `Instant` too represents a moment in UTC. Both classes represent a count since the first moment of 1970 in UTC.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Thank you for a such detailed explanation! Still, I don't understand why, after executing the Oracle SQL I wrote above, in the constructor of Timestamp comes the value 1536831971599 instead of 1536842771599. Based on the documentation System.currentTimeMillis() returns UTC, and I select from Oracle UTC also. Why the values differ exactly by my time zone, i.e. GMT+03:00?

Comment: I updated the question, maybe this will clarify my confusion. Thank you!